# Session keeps getting Error

Tags: php, html

On my `index.php` page I have this:

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['logged_in']==true) {
   header("Location:home.php");
} else {
   header("Location:login.php");
}
```

On my login page, whenever the user correctly inputs the username and password I wrote this:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

I used this as a reference to the future pages. But on my `home.php`, no matter what I do it keeps giving me this error:

```
 Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\home.php on line 8
```

The line 8 is:

```
$user= $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: why the two different session arrays?

Comment: and start the session in the 2nd file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to call session_start() on each php file that is loaded.**

Since php works by parsing each php file individually, you will have to have this at every page you have.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

In `home.php` you must call `session_start();` at the very beginning of the file too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that you will only have to call a `session_start()` only once per site. That's why I only placed it on the `index.php`